# SQL oracle how to check if current date's day is greater than concrete day

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check if current sysdate's day is greater than 10.

By using sysdate function I get todays date, which is 2017.09.27. How can I check if 27 is greater than 10?

```
SELECT * from emp
where sysdate >= 'YYYY, DD, 10'
```

This is the only solution I can think of (it's ofcourse incorrect).
Thanks for help.

Comment: Google is your friend, try extract  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'DD' date format to convert sysdate to a character string which is the day part of the date. i.e. '26' for today. Convert that string to a number and compare to 10.

```
SQL> select 'greater than 10' from dual where to_number(to_char(sysdate,'DD')) > 10;

'GREATERTHAN10'
---------------
greater than 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * from emp
where TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD')) >= 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the day from the date:

```
select [ ... ]
where extract(day from SYSDATE) > 10;
```